# What is a person's consciousness in the next world?

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come, psych-mentalhealth

I have heard in the name of the baalei mussar that the same consciousness you have in this world carries through to the next. In other words the same "I" that you relate to in this world remains the same in the next world. 
My question is if anyone has seen this idea talked about and if so where?
Thanks!

Comment: what else could it be? if there is no I how can there be any reward and punishment there?

Comment: @ray Maybe there is an I but not the same I as I identify with now.

Answer (score 4):

Rachel still cries over her children which evokes divine pity. (yirmiyahu, 31:14)

MoShe's grave was hidden from us because he could still nullify evil decrees if we were able to alert him of them. (sotah, 14a, see the Bach's edit)

Yitzchak argues for our salvation where Abraham and yaakov say to blot us out, claiming that only 12.5 years of sin are present in a man's life that he is accountable for, and either Gd can take that on, he can split it with Gd, or Yitzchak can take all of it, since he offered himself to Gd. (shabbos 89b)

it seems that though there is not change available to a person after death, their personalities remain intact, as does their level of righteousness.

Answer (score 0):

Here's 3 starting points:

1. Korach; even after *going down to hell* is still battling with Moshe's authority. He continuously yells **משה אמת ותורתו אמת  - Moshe is true and his Torah is true** and then adds **ואנחנו בדאים - and we are liars** - which some want to even interpret as meaning **what I just said** - about Moshe being true - is false.
2. In a similar vain, Chazal tell us that the wicked do not repent, even at the door to Gehinom.
3. The Gemora tells us that *in the future* the Evil Inclination will be publicly slaughtered, and both the wicked and the righteous will cry. The former because they perceive the it as a tiny hair they simply had to deal with. The latter because they see this huge mountain being slaughtered.

Comment: Did you get former and latter reversed, or is there a more subtle point I am not getting?

Comment: @Ariel, no, Danny was correctly citing the gemara in BT Sukkah 52a: the righteous will weep, saying: "How did we overcome this mountain?", while the wicked will weep, saying: "How were we unable to overcome this hair?" A beautiful teaching.